# Where does UTUBE (YouTube downloader) save files?

Tags: snap, downloads, youtube

I have just installed UTube downloader on my Ubuntu system. It works great, except I can't locate the downloaded files after I close UTube.

Comment: Dear close voter: This is an Ubuntu application: https://snapcraft.io/install/utube/ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

I downloaded the 'Utube - Complete Youtube App for Linux' as follows:

```
sudo snap install utube
```

After I downloaded some Rammstein (always a good test!) as follows:

[image]

Looks like there is a cut down version of mpv available for playback *from within the application itself*, which doubtless you have already discovered, but a simple search found my test download of Rammstein tucked away in `$HOME`. The location is a somewhat *labyrinthine* one:

```
~/snap/utube/16/.local/share/org.keshavnrj.ubuntu/Utube/downloadedVideos
```

And as long as you have installed UTube via snap, as I have, your downloaded media files will also be in this location...

Comment: +1  Better answer than mine was!  =)

Comment: @Terrance Thanks! We must have posted within seconds of each other :)

Answer (score 0):

There is now an option in the settings dialog  which  let you directly  open the download  folder. 
**snap refresh utube** 
To update  to latest version.